# Solving system of polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, matrix-equations

I'm trying to create a logic for GeoLocation mapping.

I am trying to "triangulate" a location on a unscaled illustrative map using list of GPS locations I acutally have mapped (so a list of GPS coordinates vs their relative (x,y) coordinates on the map) and the GPS coordinate of the device. I have tried to achieve this by finding the three closest point that is known, and the actual distance to these locations (by using the GPS coordinates). Given the actual distances can only be used as indicative "ratios" of the distance, I have tackled this problem as a problem of intersecting circles, as below.

Problem:

$(x_a-x)^2+(y_a-y)^2=(r*a)^2$

$(x_b-x)^2+(y_b-y)^2=(r*b)^2$

$(x_c-x)^2+(y_c-y)^2=(r*c)^2$

known variables: $x_a, x_b, x_c, y_a, y_b, y_c, a, b, c$

unknown variables: $x, y, r$

final solution: solve for the $x$ and $y$ for $r$ that gives a unique solution.

Thanks to some help here I found out this fails for some cases (namely when one of the places are too close (which is very possible) and it gives very little freedom for the other two circles to grow.

What are possible other ways the problem can be tackled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expand the squares:$$x^2 - 2x_ax +x_a^2 +y^2 - 2y_ay +y_a^2 = r^2a^2$$. Take the difference between any two lines: $$x_a^2 + y_a^2 - x_b^2 - y_b^2 = r^2(a^2-b^2) + 2(x_a - x_b)x + 2(y_a - y_b)y$$
Do this with all three pairs of equations and you have three linear equations in $x, y, r^2$. Solve them as you would any system of three linear equations. Take the square root of $r^2$ and you are done (without need to stop at the intermediary solution).

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. How could I ensure $r^2$ is positive when solving the three linear equations? (I get negative and therefore fails)

Comment: (I have no idea why some people are so quick to put things on "hold". I fail to see at all how their supposed reasons apply here.) If you are getting negative $r^2$, then something is wrong, because this is clearly solvable unless the three centers are co-linear (or possibly not if two of $a,b,c$ are the same - I'd have to think that case out a little more). Are you sure you haven't made an error in your calculations?

Comment: Come to think of it, it can also fail if one of the circles is much farther away than the other two. When $r$ is very small, you have 3 disjoint circles. Let $r$ grow. Two of the circles will intersect. As they continue to grow eventually the third circle will reach place where it passes through the point of intersection, which gives the 3-way intersection you are after. But if the third circle is too far away, the first two circles could grow to the point where they dis-engage before it gets there (after which one of the first two circles will be inside the other), and there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks, indeed agreed there's no doubt your answer is a very clean and correct solution in case a solution exists. I've tried to put the context of the issue here which may have been a better idea to do from start as well. Looks like it will be difficult to apply this problem itself to my case as there will be too many cases without a "real solution" (exactly the case you have pointed out, as well as in case if one of the point is too close as the other two circles will essentially have to intersect at a point). I'll try to find another approach for the case.